# Select points within a buffer around a line

Tags: postgis, postgresql, buffer, union, st-distance

Working with PostgreSQL. I have a Table with streets (Linestrings), and a Table with accidents (Points). The streets are divided into sections. I want to find the accidents within 50m around a certain street. I used  ST_Union to combine the Street segments to select a certain street, then made a Buffer around it, but when I try to select the accidents within the buffer QGIS crashes, guess there might be something wrong.

```
SELECT 1 as Id, c.accidents  
ST_UNION (a.geom)   
FROM Roads a, roads b, accidents c  
WHERE a.roadname = 'A3'  
AND st_distance (a.geom, b.geom) < 50  
AND ST_Within (c.geom, ST_Buffer (a.geom, 50))  
GROUP BY a.geom, c.accidents
```

Comment: PostGIS has an `ST_DWithin` operator. Use that instead. Also, multiple tables in `FROM` is an ancient practice -- use a `JOIN` operator. More details about the "crash" are necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For proximity searches better use `ST_DWithin`, as it is highly optimized to use the spatial index:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       a.accidents,
       a.geom
FROM   roads AS r
JOIN   accidents AS a
  ON   ST_DWithin(r.geom, a.geom, <distance>)
WHERE  r.roadname = 'A3'
;
```

This will find all `accidents` that are within `<distance>`**¹** of any segment with name `A3`; the `DISTINCT` will ensure that no `accidents` is returned more than once.

I do not `ST_Union` (or `ST_Collect`) the segments; the index works best on small geometric entities (and on-the-fly created geometries are (usually, if not explicitly functionally indexed) not covered by the index)

---

**¹** the `<distance>` will be treated as CRS units! If you are working with a projected CRS (with units as *meter*), using `50` is correct; if your data is referenced in a geographic CRS, units will be *degrees*! In that case, a cast to`GEOGRAPHY` is the way to go.

Comment: Also, you may want to avoid naming columns like the tables they are in (I read that your *id* column is `accidents.accidents`?); next to overall confusion and the general practice of relational naming, there are situations where PostgreSQL is sensitive about this.

Comment: After deleting a.geom (SELECT ...a.geom) it worked.
Thaaaaank you for the explanations. I know "join" is better, but sometimes I forget to use it.